# Not able to change the size of captcha in PHP

Tags: php, captcha, font-size

I have the following captcha plug-in.

I tried changing different font-size but none of them worked.

Could anyone tell me how to change the font-size please.

Thanks in advance.

**EDITED: [Code Here](http://pastie.org/780995).**

Comment: So much code makes my browser hang, use Pastie next time.

Answer (score 0):

This captcha is garbage and this code is poorly written.  You should use reCapthca,  it is very good and its free.

I have the right to say that that this capthca is garbage because I break capthcas: 
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-2019
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-3573
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-2020
http://web.nvd.nist.gov/view/vuln/detail?vulnId=CVE-2008-3573
(Or atleast in 2008 I did :)

But to actually answer your question:  On line 127 the length of the challenge is being generated. Change the number 6 to whatever you want.

```
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++)
    {
        $str .= substr($pool, mt_rand(0, strlen($pool) -1), 1);
    }
```

Comment: Any reason why all other answer are downvoted? At least I can say that this isn't an answer to that question: The *font size* should be changed not the *length* of the captcha!

Comment: It is the line for the number of letters.

Comment: shin was talking about that this is not the correct answer to the question, just read carefully...

Comment: The correct answer is to delete this extremely insecure capthca from every drive on the planet.

Comment: Yes, neo is right. It is not what I am asking for. But thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Change the font size in this piece of code, and enter higher values for the call to `mt_rand`.

```
if ($use_font == FALSE)
{
    //$font_size = 5;
    $font_size = 15;//For example
    $x = rand(2, $img_width/($length/3));
    // y isnt used here
}
else
{
    // Make font proportional to the image size
   // $font_size  = !empty($font_size) ? $font_size : mt_rand(18,25);
      $font_size  = !empty($font_size) ? $font_size : mt_rand(25,29);//For example
    $x = rand(4, $img_width - (($font_size + ($font_size >> 1)) * $length));
    // y isnt used here
}
```

Also make sure the `$img_width` and the `$img_height` are big enough so larger fonts will fit in the image.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to try to write under that:

```
$defaults = array('word' => '', 'img_path' => '', 'img_url' => '', 'img_width' => '150', 'img_height' => '30', 'font_size' => '', 'font_path' => '', 'show_grid' => true, 'skew' => true, 'expiration' => 7200);
```

the following line

```
$defaults['font_size'] = 0;
```

(and change the `0` to your desired size of course)